# SSL error when connecting via SSL for email settings

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, unix

I would try to give more info but I have no idea why this error is being caused. I have found a number of these errors in the error.log file.

I am using Debain and iRedMail.

Can anybody help with this?

```
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [info] [client ::1] Connection to child 1 established (server example.co.uk:443)
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [info] Seeding PRNG with 648 bytes of entropy
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1754): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1762): OpenSSL: Loop: before/accept initialization
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1832): OpenSSL: read 11/11 bytes from BIO#8e5dd80 [mem: 8efb668] (BIO dump follows)
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1765): +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1804): | 0000: 4f 50 54 49 4f 4e 53 20-2a 20 48                 OPTIONS * H      |
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1810): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1791): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [info] [client ::1] (os 0x08e37090)Unrecognized resolver error: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server example.co.uk:443)
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [info] SSL Library Error: 336027900 error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol speaking not SSL to HTTPS port!?
[Sun Aug 14 00:45:15 2011] [info] [client ::1] Connection closed to child 1 with abortive shutdown (server example.co.uk:443)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key clue is in the second last line:

```
unknown protocol speaking not SSL to HTTPS port!?
```

(Technically, the protocol dump on line 7 gives you a similar hint, but it's a lot more cryptic)

You may *think* you're talking SSL to the server, but in actual fact the client is speaking regular ol' HTTP.  Change your URL to be `https://` and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
OPTIONS * H
```

looks like a http OPTIONS request (which is plain instead of ssl????)

i have found that Google Chrome is making these requests after my page loaded, but i do not use ssl on the site/page

i cant find any reference for this in chrome://net-internals/#events

at least i would like to know why these requests are made, but i hope this helps peaple (as google droped me here)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that you are actually generating the errors based on your access to the web server? It looks like it may be instances of someone running a port scanner, possibly looking for web proxies - which does occur.